# Make it a compound sentence question

Tags: grammar

Make it a compound sentence:

> Enticingly served, it comes in four bowls.

I had this today in my exam and I wrote
`It comes enticingly served in four bowls.` Is this correct? If not, what is the correct version?

Comment: How's your solution 'compound'?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's the reason I asked the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it into a compound sentence, write

> It is enticingly served, and it comes in four bowls.

Comment: This looks correct. Darn I lost one mark.

Comment: Something else more important than marks: **learning**.  Whether you learn it before the exam, and get credit for it, or after the exam, where you got it wrong, the important thing is that you ultimately learn.  "Better to guess wrong and still learn, than guess correctly and learn nothing."